# How can I see output of dbms_output.put_line() in SQL window in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: plsqldeveloper, dbms-output

I'm not able to see the messages added to dbms_output.put_line() in PL/SQL Developer. Every google hit I see says to use `set serveroutput on` but this isn't working.

I try to run this script in a SQL Window:

```
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('hello')
END
```

But I get an error on the `set serveroutput on` line:

[image]

And I get no output in the Output tab (regardless of whether I have the `set serveroutput on`):

[image]

How can I see the output sent to dbms_output.put_line('hello') in a script run in an SQL Window?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in PL/SQL Developer, a SQL Window can only contain either SQL or PL/SQL blocks. There is a checkbox for enabling or disabling dbms_output. SQL windows aren't really for scripts, unless the 'script' is [a set of SQL queries](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/performance-for-sqlid.html) or PL/SQL blocks and nothing else.

[image]

[image: PL/SQL Developer SQL Window screenshot - output]

(If there is more than one statement in the window, it may be helpful to add `/` as a terminator after the PL/SQL block, otherwise PL/SQL Developer won't know where one statement ends and the next begins unless you explicitly highlight it with the mouse.)

Alternatively, you could use `set serverout on` in a Command window (which is a SQL*Plus emulator), or better, use a Test window, which is specifically designed for executing PL/SQL blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer William. That certainly helps.