# How do I get dbms_output to show when running a script in command window in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: plsqldeveloper, dbms-output, command-window

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71638099/how-can-i-see-output-of-dbms-output-put-line-in-sql-window-in-pl-sql-developer)

I am trying to run the following script in PL/SQL Developer in a Command Window:

```
DECLARE
  ncount NUMBER;
  vwhere VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
  vselect VARCHAR2(1000) := ' select count(1) from ';
  vsearchstr VARCHAR2(1000) := 'put your string here';
  vline VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  FOR k IN (SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name
    FROM user_tab_cols a
    WHERE a.data_type LIKE '%VARCHAR%')
  LOOP
    vwhere := ' where ' || k.column_name || ' = :vsearchstr ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vselect || k.table_name || vwhere
      INTO ncount
      USING vsearchstr;
    IF (ncount > 0)
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(k.column_name || ' ' || k.table_name);
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('no output');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.get_line(vline, istatus);
END;
/
```

This script is supposed to search the entire database for the string given in `vsearchstr` and output the table and column it found it in. It outputs 'no output' if the string isn't found.

When I run it, it tells me `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed` but I do not see any output coming from dbms_output. I expect to see something regardless of the results of the script as it outputs something to dbms_output regardless of whether it finds the string or not. This is the case even when I turn on serveroutput with `set serveroutput on` before running the script.

Can anyone tell what's wrong? Is the output being printed somewhere else? Where would this be?

Comment: Google SET SERVER OUTPUT ON

Comment: If the question is *How do I get dbms_output to show when running a script in a command window?* then it would be best not to complicate the test with all the loops and conditional logic in your question. Just `begin dbms_output.put_line('Hello'); end;` and lose the rest.

Comment: There is rarely any point in calling `dbms_output.enable`. If it's not already enabled in the calling application, it won't get the lines and print them after the database call.

Comment: Just to add, a Test window is generally best for running a single PL/SQL block like this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem wasn't with dbms_output, but two things: 1) `dbms_output.get_line(vline, istatus)` was clearing the output buffer, and 2) there were only a limit set of table the FOR loop was searching through, none of which had any VARCHAR columns. I am expanding my search to all_tab_columns.